# Why is this transformation not invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrmgt.png

Why did they set the matrix to [0 1] and why is it not invertible?

This is the original transformation, and I have provided the solution in the top.
|$y_1$| = |$x_1$ + $x_2$|
|$y_2$| = |$x_1$ ⋅ $x_2$|

Answer (score 2):

We are given a map $T:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ defined by
$$
T(x_1,x_2)=(x_1+x_2,x_1\cdot x_2)
$$
To prove that $T$ is not invertible we will show that $T$ is not surjective. In particular, we will show that there exists no $x\in\Bbb R^2$ such that $T(x)=(0,1)$.

Indeed suppose $T(x_1,x_2)=(0,1)$. Then $x_2=-x_1$ so that
$$
x_1\cdot x_2=-x_1^2\leq 0
$$
That is, $x_1\cdot x_2\neq 1$, a contradiction.

Note that the language of matrices is being used in this problem for organizational purposes only. There is no matrix that we are testing for invertability.